# Portainer: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket

Tags: docker, portainer

I'm on a fresh Fedora CoreOS which comes with Docker version 19.03.11.

My `core` user is in the `docker` group:

```
[core@localhost ~]$ groups
core adm wheel sudo systemd-journal docker
```

Following the [deployment instructions for portainer](https://portainer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment.html), I create a new Portainer container like this (as `core` or `root`, it doesn't even matter):

```
$ docker volume create portainer_data
$ docker run -d -p 9000:9000 -p 8000:8000 --name portainer --restart always -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v portainer_data:/data portainer/portainer
```

And when I try to connect to the local daemon:

[image: Permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket]

Permissions of `/var/run/docker.sock`:

```
[core@localhost ~]$ ll /var/run/docker.sock
srw-rw----. 1 root docker 0 Aug  2 10:02 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Even if I `chmod o+rw` `/var/run/docker.sock` it doesn't work. This indicates that the problem might be in the container itself so  I tried to access it but I can't:

```
[core@localhost ~]$ docker exec -it portainer sh
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

All resources I found so far suggest to add the user to the `docker` group, which I did, reboot the machine, which I did, or set 666 on `/var/run/docker.sock`, which I did but prefer not to. Nothing helped.

Any idea what's wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a SELinux issue, try first to follow [`portainer/portainer` issue 849](https://github.com/portainer/portainer/issues/849)

> Correct way is to add :z to the volume mapping, so you're not defeating the purpose of docker.
>
> Like so:
>
> ```
> docker run -d -p 9000:9000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:z portainer/portainer
> ```
>
> Also we need a way to add the z or Z flag in Portainer for new containers. This has been a feature since 1.7 e.g. 2015 in Docker.

That, or using [`dpw/selinux-dockersock`](https://github.com/dpw/selinux-dockersock)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to MrPaperbag on the Portainer Discord I found out it's because of a restriction by SELinux.

Found the solution here: https://nanxiao.me/en/selinux-cause-permission-denied-issue-in-using-docker/

Either run `docker run` with `--privileged`, or set SELinux mode as permissive using `setenforce 0`. Probably there's a way to properly configure SELinux instead of just circumventing it, however, for my use case this is good enough.